# Passing va_list to #define which only accepts variable args (...)

Tags: c++, c, printf, variadic-functions

I have a preprocessor define that only accepts variable args and not a va_list.

```
#define DEBUG(fmt, args...)                                         \
    do {                                                            \
            debug_printk(CORE, NAME,              \
                                    __func__, fmt, ##args);         \
    } while (0)

void write(const char* fmt, ...)
{
     va_list args;
     va_start(args, fmt);
     print_debug(fmt, &args);
     va_end(args);

}

void print_debug(const char* fmt, va_list* args)
{
     DEBUG(fmt, *args);
}
```

Is there any way to pass a va_list arg variable to this? I don't have the ability to change this define, and there doesn't appear to be a VDEBUG alternative.

What are my options?

Thanks

Edit:

I guess the best way would be to use vsnprintf to get a string, and then passing that to DEBUG using DEBUG("%s", buffer);

Comment: Variadic arguments for macros aren't the same as variadic arguments to functions, because macros are not functions.

Comment: @H2CO3: right, so passing a va_list to debug_printk then, same problem, isn't it?

Comment: Um, yes, I think I slightly misunderstood the problem.

Comment: However, you *can* definitely make the `VDEBUG()` macro using the `vprintk()` function.

Comment: @H2CO3: the debug_printk function is the only one that exists, and it's in another part of the code that I can't modify. I mean, sure I can create my own macro for vprintk, but that doesn't call the function I need to call with the appropriate params.

Comment: So after all, what is "the function you need to call"?

Comment: debug_printk(), but let's just assume it's a black box for now. But it takes in paramets such as void debug_printk(char*, char*, char*, const char* fmt, ...){}

Comment: Then that's simple, you can't call it with a `va_list`.

Comment: @H2CO3 So then back to my original question, what are my options?

Comment: So then back to my original suggestion: write your own macro.

Comment: @H2CO3: Seriously? I *just* said that I can't, because it's calling a function in code that I can't modify that only accepts ... as arguments. What would this macro do? As I said, debug_printk is in an area I can't change, so writing my own macro would be comepletely useless because I can't call the correct function... I feel like we're going in circles.

Comment: You can't do exactly what you want. Accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the best way would be to use vsnprintf to get a string, and then passing that to DEBUG using DEBUG("%s", buffer);